# creating data frame for confusionMatrix(0 input, however getting unusual dataframe

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I’m try to understand results of a prediction object via caret’s confusionMatrix() function, which requires table input according to http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/caret/html/confusionMatrix.html, my table() creates results that I understand , but its not friendly to the confusionMatrix() function.

**Here is the relevant code snippet:**

```
#MODEL CREATION
#convert categorical A to E values , into numeric 1 to 5 in order to be regression friendly
training_data_subset_numeric <- training_data_subset;
testing_data_subset_numeric <- testing_data_subset;
training_data_subset_numeric$classe <- as.numeric(training_data_subset$classe)
testing_data_subset_numeric$classe <- as.numeric(testing_data_subset$classe)
#model
exercise.model <- glm(formula = classe ~ ., data = training_data_subset_numeric)
#MODEL EVALUATION
exercise.prediction <- predict(exercise.model,newdata = testing_data_subset_numeric)
eval_table <- table(exercise.prediction,testing_data_subset$classe)
tail(eval_table)

exercise.prediction A B C D E
   4.35504232913594 1 0 0 0 0
   4.47219097065568 1 0 0 0 0
   4.50838854075835 1 0 0 0 0
   4.6173551930011  0 1 0 0 0
   4.69261223447305 0 1 0 0 0
   4.73297946213265 0 1 0 0 0
```

**Basically I need to convert the above output , to a data frame with 1 col corresponding to prediction value that follows this rule:**

If column A is 1 , than predicted value is 1

If column B is 1 , than predicted  value is 2

If column C is 1 , than predicted  value is 3

If column D is 1 , than predicted  value is 4

If column E is 1 , than predicted  value is 5

**I therefore, wrote this function to get the job done:**

```
getPredictResults<- function(x)
{
# create 1 column & n row data frame
num <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(x)));

for (r in 1:nrow(x) ) {

for (c in 1:ncol(x) ) {
    #if column A has value 1 than num[1,r] <- 1
     if (x[r,'A']== 1)
    {
        num[1,r] <- 1;
    }
    #if column B has value 1 than num[1,r] <- 2
    else if (x[r,'B']== 1)
    {
        num[1,r] <- 2;
    }
    #if column C has value 1 than num[1,r] <- 3
    else if (x[r,'C']== 1)
    {
        num[1,r] <- 3;
    }
    #if column D has value 1 than num[1,r] <- 4
    else if (x[r,'D']== 1)
    {
        num[1,r] <- 4;
    }
    #if column E has value 1 than num[1,r] <- 5
    else if (x[r,'E']== 1)
    {
        num[1,r] <- 5;
    }
    else
    {
    }

}#end inner for 

}#end outer for 

return (num);
}#end function

exercise.prediction_df <- getPredictResults(eval_table)
```

However when typing :

```
head(exercise.prediction_df)
```

**Im getting an unusual output , here is the bottom snippet:**

```
2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  V4840 V4841 V4842 V4843 V4844 V4845 V4846 V4847 V4848 V4849 V4850 V4851 V4852 V4853 V4854 V4855 V4856 V4857
1     5     1     4     5     2     2     5     5     1     2     5     4     5     5     1     5     5     4
2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  V4858 V4859 V4860 V4861 V4862 V4863 V4864 V4865 V4866 V4867 V4868 V4869 V4870 V4871 V4872 V4873 V4874 V4875
1     4     2     1     2     5     1     4     5     2     1     4     5     2     4     2     4     4     2
2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  V4876 V4877 V4878 V4879 V4880 V4881 V4882 V4883 V4884 V4885 V4886 V4887 V4888 V4889 V4890 V4891 V4892 V4893
1     5     1     1     4     1     2     2     1     1     5     1     4     1     1     1     1     1     1
2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  V4894 V4895 V4896 V4897 V4898 V4899 V4900 V4901 V4902 V4903 V4904
1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2
2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4 rows ]
```

**Further investigation shows:**

```
> ncol(exercise.prediction_df)
[1] 4904
> nrow(exercise.prediction_df)
[1] 4904
```

Which ncol() should only return 1 & nrow() obviously can be any integer value.

How can I fix this function, in order to create the right dataframe as an input to confusionMatrix() function?

Thanks.

Comment: I didnt ask "whether this algorithm was optimal?" This wouldnt even be the right forum, please read my question, carefully, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
classe <- cut(runif(100), seq(0, 1, length.out = 5))
levels(a) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
exercise.prediction <- rnorm(100)
eval_table <- table(exercise.prediction, classe)

eval_matrix <- as.matrix(tab)

transform <- apply(eval_matrix, 1, function(x) sum(x * c(1:5)))
head(as.data.frame(transform))
```

Comment: Did you read the question? The algorithm is already written, I'm just wandering why the data is being coerced incorrectly, no need to multiply anything. By the way your input is incorrect , please refer to my input which is the result of the predict() function.

Comment: 1. Yes I have read the question, you did not provide a reproducible example, so I assumed you were able to transform the A-E columns in your `eval_table` to a matrix or data frame (see the edits to my answer). I honestly don't have a clue why your function doesn't work, and I'm not going to figure it out. My solution works and is two lines, yours is about 30 and involves a nested loop, which is not good R style. 2. If you ask people to help you for free you might consider the tone of your replies.